# How to tell a field is nvarchar in CakePHP

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, cakephp, utf-8, cakephp-1.2

I want to make sure that the strings I save to the database are properly formatted in UTF-8. I have converted some of the fields into nvarchar. To save the strings properly I need to prefix all strings with N. e.g. `N'my string'`.

However not all fields are necessarily nvarchar. In the [DboSqlsrv](https://github.com/revathskumar/CakePHP-sqlsrv-driver) class that I am using that extends DboSource, there is just the one string parameter that you can either specify as 'varchar' or 'nvarchar'.

Does anybody know if there is a 'cake' way to interrogate the database and check if a field is varchar or nvarchar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this? http://book.cakephp.org/view/1066/_schema

Comment: thanks. That's pointed me in the right direction. I'm guessing for strings there is only the string and text types. I can use nvarchar for one and varchar for the other.